# Scale is being ignored by d3.behavior.zoom()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have setup this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjgxdw42/) to try to figure out why the scale that I pass to `d3.behavior.zoom()` is being ignored. I am setting the scale to 10 but the effective scale is 1. Then if I try to pan the grid the scale jumps to 10. Same thing happens when I try to zoom the grid. The scale jumps to 10 and then the additional scale is applied. What am I doing wrong? How can I work this out in order to have an effective initial scale value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing a `var scale = 10` to represent that initial zoom, and you're applying that to `zoomer` via `.scale(10)`. So `zoomer` knows the initial scale, but nothing in your code is doing the work of **applying the initial scale to the d3 selection** `vis`. The first time the scale is actually applied is once the user interacts, which in turn calls `function zoom() {...}`, where the scale is finally applied.

The time/place to apply the initial scale, is when you create `vis`:

```
//create a group that will hold all the content to be zoomed
var vis = graph.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "plotting-area")
    .attr("transform", "scale(" + scale + ")");// <-- THIS
```

Here's [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjgxdw42/1/)